# Chrome on Linux - query the browser to see what tabs are open?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, chromium, desktop-integration

I am running Chromium (the open source chrome version) on Ubuntu Linux. Can I write a programme to see what tabs I have open? I would like to write a programme to monitor how much time I'm spending on things. Is there a command line programme, some way to invoke the chromium-browser command, or some dbus incantation that will tell me what tabs I have open and what URL each tab is at?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed there is a command line option which can open the door to a running chrome (chromium) process `--remote-shell-port`. Through this "debugging back-door" you may be able the get the list of open tabs.

- Look at [chromedevtools](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/) for further inspiration.

UPDATE:

[Chrome DevTools](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/ChromeDevToolsProtocol#Deprecation_And_Removal) is deprecated and not supported anymore since Version >17.0.950.* 
See [WebKit-Protocol](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/WebKitProtocol) manual if the new Debug-Framework provides similar manners to accomplish the task.

Comment: Is it possible to access the list of open tabs from a Google Chrome extension?

Comment: This question explains how to find the list of open tabs from a Chrome extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915370/retrieving-which-tabs-are-open-in-chrome

Comment: Does this answer apply to all platforms, or does it only apply to Linux?

Answer (score 11):

[Chrome on Linux - query the browser to see what tabs are open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968271/chrome-on-linux-query-the-browser-to-see-what-tabs-are-openFor)

For `chromium` :

```
strings ~/'.config/chromium/Default/Current Session' | 'grep' -E '^https?://'
```

Comment: I know nobody asked for mac, but I was linked to this question when googling for a mac answer, so I'm just gonna add the info here.  `strings ~/'Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Current Session' | 'grep' -E '^https?://'`

Comment: It gives an error like `No such file or directory`. Can you help, please?

Comment: it sorta works. returns urls that are not currently open too, but i suppose thats to be expected based on what `strings` does

Comment: Is there a way to get which tab I'm focusing?

Comment: Maybe the last one of the `https` is, thanks. And `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/'Current Session'` for Chrome.

Comment: Does someone have a windows solution ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more general solution (works with other applications as well) by querying the X window under focus using **xdotool**

```
while true; do 
  xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname; 
  sleep 10; 
done
```

This outputs the following for instance:

```
Tilix: Defaultpeter-ThinkPad-T5801: peter@peter-ThinkPad-T580: ~
Chrome on Linux - query the browser to see what tabs are open? - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome
Local KVM
untitled — Atom
untitled — Atom
Open File
iostat_xtmz_3.out — ~/Work/KappAhl/Test1 — Atom
Tilix: Defaultpeter-ThinkPad-T5801: peter@peter-ThinkPad-T580: ~*
```

Comment: But that took you 80 seconds,

Comment: xdotool seems to only know the currently open tab, but not all the other tabs.

Answer (score 2):

An expansion on the unix command above (I don't have enough reputation to comment). I was trying to just get a count of tabs. This still isn't perfect because I think the file has the entire history of all tabs in it. I guess they are in order, but not obvious how to separate them.

`strings ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Sessions/Tabs_* | sed -nE 's/^([^:]+):\/\/(.*)\/$/\2/p' | grep -v "newtab" | grep -v "new-tab-page" | sort | uniq | wc -l`

This is on mac, so your paths and sed options may vary.

The basic idea is to get rid of trailing slashes (lots of redirects just add a slash) and newtabs so we can get an accurate count. For my current tabs file this went from 181 tabs open down to a count of 35. That actually looks like an undercount right now, but it is a lot closer.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a tool to extract data from chrome session files for precisely this purpose. https://github.com/lemnos/chrome-session-dump. Running it like so chrome-session-dump will produce a list of tabs (in order) which can subsequently be passed to firefox. E.G chrome-session-dump|xargs firefox. You can also obtain the currently open tab via -active for processing by external scripts.

Comment: Hi, I get the error 'panic: Unable to find session file.', can you help me?